# Value returned as Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement a shake detection using phonegap and unfortunately I am having an issue with values being returned as undefined.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
function acc() {
var accOpt = { frequency: 1000 };   
watchPot = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(win, fail, accOpt);    
}

function win (acceleration) {

    var tiltLR = 0;
    var tiltFB = 0;

    var facingUp = -1;
    if (acceleration.z > 0) {
      facingUp = +1;
    }

    tiltLR = Math.round(((acceleration.x) / 9.81) * -90);
    tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.y + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);

      previousReading = {
        x   :   null,
        y   :   null,
        z   :   null,
        lr  :   null,
        fb  :   null            
      };

      var changes = {};

      if (previousReading.x !== null) {
          changes.x = Math.abs(previousReading.x-acceleration.x);
          changes.y = Math.abs(previousReading.y-acceleration.y);
          changes.z = Math.abs(previousReading.z-acceleration.z);
          changes.lr = Math.abs(previousReading.lr-tiltLR);
          changes.fb = Math.abs(previousReading.fb-tiltFB);
      }

      previousReading = {
          x: acceleration.x,
          y: acceleration.y,
          z: acceleration.z,
          lr: tiltLR,
          fb: tiltFB
      };


    console.log('previousReading x: ' + previousReading.x + ' previousReading y: ' + previousReading.y + ' previousReading z: ' + previousReading.z+ ' previousReading lr: ' + tiltLR + ' previousReading fb: ' + tiltFB);

    console.log('changes x: ' + changes.x  + ' changes y: ' + changes.y + ' changes z: ' + changes.z + ' changes lr: ' + changes.lr + ' changes fb: ' + changes.fb);

    console.log(acceleration.x + ' ' + acceleration.y + ' ' + acceleration.z);

 }
```

Basically the values for acceleration x, y, z and the value for the previous reading are being logged in the console properly.

However the issue is with the values for changes.x, changes.y and changes.z which are all returning undefined for some reason.

I have also tried to check the typeof(changes.x) and it returned undefined as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the code you provided, `changes.x, changes.y` and `changes.z` aren't set because  `if (previousReading.x !== null) {` will evaluate to false because `previousReading.x` is explicity set to null here:

```
 previousReading = {
    x   :   null,
    y   :   null,
    z   :   null,
    lr  :   null,
    fb  :   null            
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you are working with integers so use this:

```
 previousReading = {
    x   :   0,
    y   :   0,
    z   :   0,
    lr  :   0,
    fb  :   0            
  };
```